# PHP Find extension of image from url with no extension

Tags: php

I have a url like so:

```
$file="http://example.com/307i215/sn9gyyzpry09m3e97z6hhbnw84i215";
```

It will either be an image or a video but it does not have the extension within the url.

How can I get the extension of this file from the url so that I can save it with the right extension?

```
$extension=?;    
copy($file,"newname.$extension");
```

Comment: Have you tried [mime-content-type](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mime-content-type.php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
$file="http://example.com/307i215/sn9gyyzpry09m3e97z6hhbnw84i215";
//copy file to server

$type= mime_content_type($file)
//rename file based on the type
```

output

```
image/gif
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Oh alright! Do I have to save the file with an extension? Will it matter if I don't? Or should I rename it after I find the content type?

Comment: It is better to save and find the file type and rename it back

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for your information:

```
$extension=get_headers($file,1)["Content-Type"];
```

Will output `image/gif` before copy.